# combining info from three classes into fourth class

Tags: java, class

Trying to create a class that would pull info from 3 classes that were already created (they calculate tax rates after a specific number is entered, all three have different taxes).  Example of one of the classes is below.

What's the best way to select each one of these classes through System.out.print("Enter the...  and then entering the amount that would be taxed?

or should the three classes by combined into one and once again through System.out.print("Enter the....  all of the info inputted?

Thanks.

```
package tax;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class china {

    private static Scanner reader;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //constants
        final double Tax_Rate = 0.20;  

        reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Variables 
        double purchases;  
        double taxespaid;   

        //Request Input 
        System.out.print("Enter your total amount of purchases in China:"); 
        purchases = reader.nextDouble();

        taxespaid = purchases * Tax_Rate;


        //Display Tax
        System.out.println("The refund amount you owed is $" + taxespaid);


    }

}
```

Comment: You can't the way you have it. You essentially have a structured program disguised as a class.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking, but I suspect that's because you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need three different classes to do something like this. Classe hierarchies ideally should be used for differing behaviour or functionality. If you want to simply store data, use a data structure. It sounds here like you are mapping a country name to a tax rate, so a Map is the data structure you are after.

Here's an quick and dirty example of using a Map in your code to achieve what you're after.

```
package tax;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Tax{

    private static Scanner reader;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //constants
        final Map<String, Double> taxRates = new HashMap<>(); 
        taxRates.put( "China", 0.2 );
        taxRates.put( "Japan", 0.1 );
        taxRates.put( "USA", 0.3 );

        reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Variables 
        double purchases;  
        double taxespaid;
        Double taxRate;   
        String country;

        System.out.print("Enter the country you are purchasing in: ");
        country = reader.nextLine();
        taxRate = taxRates.get( country );
        if( taxRate == null )
        {
            System.out.println( "Could not find country: " + country );
            return; 
        }

        //Request Input 
        System.out.print("Enter your total amount of purchases in " + country + " :"); 
        purchases = reader.nextDouble();

        taxespaid = purchases * taxRate;


        //Display Tax
        System.out.println("The refund amount you owed is $" + taxespaid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I see what you did there, but what could be the reason for the line   final Map<String, Double> taxRates = new Map<>(); giving a problem with the following messages:                          "Multiple markers at this line
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<> to 
  Map<String,Double>
 - Cannot instantiate the type Map<>
 - Cannot instantiate the type Map<String,Double>

Comment: I made an error. Map is an interface, so it cannot be instantiated. You need to use a HashMap, which is an implementation of a Map. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by you that you have three diff class for handling taxes better have single class with three diff methods and pass amt as parameter to that method. Using Scanner get two input like 1 for country and 2 for amount to be calculated. This should solve your problem.